# Debug assertion failed, invalid input format using C

Tags: c, struct

Received a debug assertion failed error message on my program, I've searched for similar questions and don't see any that relate to my problem. If someone can tell me what im doing wrong I would greatly appreciate the help. The error message says expression: invalid input format.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 20 

struct input
{
    char emplyName[5][SIZE];
    float emplyHours[5];
    float emplyRate[5];
    float emplyGross[5];
    float emplyBase[5];
    float emplyOvrt[5];
    float emplyTax[5];
    float emplyNet[5];
    float emplyTotal[5];
};

void employeeInfo(struct input *emply)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("Enter employee name -1 to end.\n");
        scanf_s("%s", &emply->emplyName[i], SIZE);
        printf("Enter employee hours.\n");
        scanf_s("%.2f", &emply->emplyHours[i]);
        printf("Enter Hourly rate.\n");
        scanf_s("%.2f", &emply->emplyRate[i]);
    }
}
void calculations(struct input *emply)/*Write a method that calculates the gross, base and overtime pay, pass by reference.*/
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        emply->emplyOvrt[i] = (emply->emplyHours[i] > 40)*(emply->emplyRate[i]);
        emply->emplyGross[i] = (((emply->emplyHours[i])*(emply->emplyRate[i])) + emply->emplyOvrt[i]);
        emply->emplyBase[i] = (emply->emplyGross[i]) - (emply->emplyOvrt[i]);
    }
}
void taxes(struct input *emply)/*Write a method that calculates tax, taking as input the gross pay, returning the tax owed.
*/
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        emply->emplyTax[i] = ((emply->emplyGross[i])*.2);
    }
}
void print(struct input *emply)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("Employee Name:%s\n", emply->emplyName[i]);
        printf("Hours Worked:%.2f\n ", emply->emplyHours[i]);
        printf("Hourly Rate:%.2f\n", emply->emplyRate[i]);
        printf("Gross Pay:%.2f\n", emply->emplyGross[i]);
        printf("Base Pay:%.2f\n", emply->emplyBase[i]);
        printf("Overtime Pay:%.2f\n", emply->emplyOvrt[i]);
        printf("Taxes Paid:%.2f\n", emply->emplyTax[i]);
        printf("Net Pay:%.2f\n", emply->emplyNet[i]);
    }
}

int main(void)
    {
        struct input payroll = { "",0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f };
        employeeInfo(&payroll);
        calculations(&payroll);
        taxes(&payroll);
        print(&payroll);

        system("pause");
    }
```

Comment: At which line you are getting the error?

Comment: I can't find the assertion statement. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: The message says line 1369... But it seems to me the problem is in lines 66-71

Comment: [sigh] not that SO code sections do not have line numbers.1369, 66-71 mean nothing here:(

Comment: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.

Comment: In main I passed an invalid parameter

Comment: Oh good, that's a start.  There are five calls in main().  What happens if you comment out the last 2, rebuild and run again?

Comment: Martin J, commented out the last 2 calls program ran asked employee name, then asked for hours and when I entered that in the same error message occurred. So I'm guessing the problem is in the employee info call.

Comment: The issue is an invalid input format string and there are only 3 calls to `scanf_s()`, so why do you guys need line numbers and crystal balls?

Comment: found the problem.. in the employee info function I was using %.2f in the scanf_s when it should have only %f .... Thanks for the help.

Comment: @cremno - an attempt to instruct the OP, and future visitors, on how to ask good questions and how to debug, something that is sorely lacking on SO.

Comment: @MartinJames: I see a beginner that is confused by a failed assertion in someone else's code requiring the usage of a debugger to find out the line no. in his code (which isn't needed anyway to answer this question since the entire code and at least the relevant part of the assertion message was posted). Where are the instructions for that? But at least you tried to help.

Comment: @cremno: One basic requirement a poster has to fullfill is to provide information about the error; at least what/where `exactly` the error message is (with reference to the posted code). If that is not clear, he can ask how to obtain that, but OP continued to ignore the requests apparently. That has nothing to do with "beginner", etc., but is just the minimal reason. Btw: If you have the answer, why do you not just post it or give advice to OP?

Comment: I fixed the bug and the program is running fine, anyone have any suggestions on how I could get a total for all the employees gross pay.

Comment: @Olaf: Because OP has found and fixed their mistake by themselves before I could. Read the comments and don't forget to consider the timestamps. By the way, thanks for deleting your rude comment.

Answer (score 0):

`%.2f` is not a valid input format specifier (it is an output format specifier).
Try using just `%f`.

Sidenote: the assert statement is actually in the implementation of the C library, not in your code. That is why you see confusing line numbers.